# How to - configure EE to play nice with https...?

Tags: ee2, ssl

Does anyone know about any resources that explain how to get EE2 to play nicely with SSL certificates please?

Thanks!

Comment: Could simply adding `https:.//'`to your general config > site settings field fix it?

Comment: Sorry, typo.... `https://`

Comment: Then add htaccess rules to force everything to https

Comment: Tried both of those, all that happens is site fails to render properly; EE is sending stuff over https: but the results in the browser are a total mess.  I can work through and debug, but rather hoped I'd missed something obvious that would avoid the need to go through asset by asset to work out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My general steps are:

1. Set up General Configuration > URL to the root directory of your site to use https.
2. Set up File Upload Preferences >  > URL of Upload Directory to use https. This makes sure your images/documents are properly linked.

To catch any other http references:

1. View source of your web page and search "http:".
2. Search for "http:" in your file tree (grep -r 'http:' /path/to/ee/root).
3. I've never had to go this far, but Developer Tools > Network might shed light if some something embedded deeper is making http calls.

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it out - a couple of EE Addons had been set with hard-wired base URL entries that I had missed - so when I set it to HTTPS operation, they continued to serve items using the hardwired (non HTTPS) URLs.  One of these was Minimee and so none of the style sheets or js loaded due to insecure content.

Comment: Could you mention the apps that require a bit of a tweak?